# What is the pupose of "col VALUE for A70" in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

With `sqlplus` command what is the use of `col VALUE for A70`

Found in many scripts but could not find the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the width of the column. A70 means 70 characters

Comment: Ok. It is like truncating at 70 of text value or substring.

Comment: @itsraja - no, it is not. If the input is shorter than 70 characters, the column width will still be 70 characters. If the input is longer, it will be *wrapped* (it will appear over multiple lines), it will not be *truncated*. It's not clear why you are asking here; do you know, in general, how to find and read "documentation"? Google for "SQLplus" and for "col" - this will take you straight to the documentation of the `COL[UMN]` command in the SQL\*Plus manual, where you can see what all the options are.